# Laravel: Why is my path variable undefined?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to attach a file sent with my form request in an email however I keep getting the following error executing the script.

> Undefined variable: filepath

```
public function postEmail(Request $request)
{
    // validate uploaded file
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'menu' => 'required|mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,application/pdf'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('signup/services')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
    }

    $filepath = $request->menu->path();

    // email file
    \Mail::send('emails.service_uploaded', ['title' => 'File Uploaded', 'message' => 'Example MSG'], function ($message)
     {
        $message->from('no-reply@mysite.com', 'My Site');
        $message->to('me@mail.com');
        $message->subject('New Upload');
        $message->attach($filepath);
    });

    // send to next page
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the $filepath variable to the Mail::send function like this

```
\Mail::send('emails.service_uploaded', ['title' => 'File Uploaded', 'message' => 'Example MSG'], function ($message) use ($filepath)
 {
    $message->from('no-reply@mysite.com', 'My Site');
    $message->to('me@mail.com');
    $message->subject('New Upload');
    $message->attach($filepath);
});
```